# ReportViewer keeps refreshing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, reportviewer, report-viewer2010, reportviewer2008

I have a very weird situation. I'm using a `ReportViewer` control in ASP.NET to show a report in my `aspx` page. This works fine when i build my web site with VS2008. But it goes wrong when i add a `Report Viewer` control to a page in VS2010...

The problem i have with the `ReportViewer` in VS2010 is that it constantly keeps refreshing my report. When i view the network traffic that i send from that page i can clearly see the `ReportViewer` is constantly sending a new request to get the report. I have no clue why it is behaving like this, and only in VS2010...

But this ONLY happends when i try to add a parameter to my report.

This is what my code looks like:

## VS2008

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana"
    Font-Size="8pt" Height="642px" ProcessingMode="Remote" Width="896px">
    <ServerReport ReportPath="http://server.com/Product/Dashboards/test.rdl" 
        ReportServerUrl="http://server.com/ReportServer" />
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

## VS2010

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" 
ProcessingMode="Remote" Width="948px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" 
     WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" 
    WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
    <ServerReport ReportPath="http://server.com/Product/Dashboards/test.rdl" 
        ReportServerUrl="http://server.com/ReportServer" />
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

## Code behind

For both `VS2008` and `VS2010` i have the following code in my `Page_Load`:

```
ReportParameter[] reportParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
reportParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("year", "2012", true);
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

---

Why do i have problems with VS2010 when i add parameters, ie: Why does it keeps refreshing my report? And why is this working perfectly fine in VS2008?

Comment: When you say constantly, do you mean it refreshs even once the page is finished loading ?

Comment: @DavidBrunelle Yes. The page loads fine. It's only the `ReportViewer` that is constantly trying to load the report.

Comment: I don't know much about reportviewer in ASP.net page, but is it possible that a property could explain this behaviour ? Something that might be new to 2010

Comment: @DavidBrunelle I looked at all the properties, but couldn't find anything "special".

Answer (score 1):

This may be the problem you're encountering:  [Reports Never Stop Loading With VS 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianhartman/archive/2010/03/21/reports-never-stop-loading-with-vs-2010.aspx)

Apparently you need a check for IsPostBack before calling SetParameters.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is in an old one, but for those still looking I had this problem in ReportViewer2012 and solved it by checking for a post back in the code behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
   {
     // Your code behind code here
   }
}
```

This may also help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/deae558c-977f-484e-86ba-50cfd376c181/reportviewer-constantly-refreshing?forum=vsreportcontrols